# Nginx redirect PHP request with parameters to other page

Tags: nginx, php

I have maybe simple question. I want to redirect redirect this myBB's page:

```
/misc.php?action=help&hid=10
```

To this one:

```
/document.html
```

I tried this in nginx's vhost config:

```
location /misc.php?action=help&hid=10 { return 301 /document.html; }
```

But it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to serverfault.com

```
location /misc.php {
    if ($args = "action=help&hid=10")  {
        return 301 /document.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: part with if statement worked, but location directive didn't... Not sure why. I finaly did it throught PHP's location directive using your if statement. Thank you for your answer. I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

nginx `location` directive does not match query parameters. Therefore you need to use the `if` approach described by Federico above.

However, you need extra configuration in the `location` block, if you want other requests to `/misc.php` to be processed by PHP. For example, you need to include the same FastCGI statements as there are inside your `location ~ \.php$` block.